How to generate windows example for my ReactNative-NativeModule library
I am trying to create my own windows library(native module) for React Native. I tried following commands
npx create-react-native-module NativeModuleSample

npx create-react-native-library@latest react-native-awesome-module

But when I tried to create a Native Module with example, these commands will create examples only for ios and android.
How to create example for windows?
I am using following command to initiate windows support for the native module
npx react-native-windows-init --version latest --projectType lib --language cs --overwrite

